# How to set a list view array from a web service

Tags: java, android, web-services, listview, arraylist

I am new to Android. I am trying to populate a list view from an array list from a web service. I have not had any luck finding the any tutorial online that uses arrays to listview. I am getting a Syntax error on token "final", invalid Type

Here is my java code:

```
public class LocationFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView tv;

    public LocationFragment() {
    }

    private String TAG = "Vik";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_location, container, false);
        tv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
        task.execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            location();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

    public void location() 
    {
        String SOAP_ACTION = "http://example.com/getlocations";
        String METHOD_NAME = "getlocations";
        String NAMESPACE = "http://example.com/";
        String URL = "http://localhost/example/Service.asmx";   

        try { 
            SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
            Request.addProperty("get locations", "null");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

            HttpTransportSE transport= new HttpTransportSE(URL);

            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

            Object result=(Object)envelope.getResponse();

            final results = (String[]) result;


            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // This code will always run on the UI thread, therefore is safe to modify UI elements.

                    ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);

                    tv.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is my web service any help would be appreciated.

```
    [WebMethod]
public string[] getlocations()
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DEV-SQL1;Initial Catalog=portal;User Id=wstest;Password=wstest;");
    List<string> locations = new List<string>();
    cn.Open();
    string sqlquery = string.Format("SELECT LocationName FROM ts_locations where CompanyID = '130' ORDER by LocationName");
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, cn);
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = com.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        locations.Add(sqlReader.GetString(0));
    }
    cn.Close();
    return locations.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://androidtutorials-codes.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-app-development-201-2nd.html) where i call a json web service populate the response data into ArrayList and populate the ListView with that ArrayList

Focus on this line here:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,titleCollection);
```

Where titleCollection is an `ArrayList<String>`